# Perform Http Post request to a Nexus API after login

Tags: java, http-post

I want to execute a POST request in java against Nexus API to promote artifact from one repository to another repo.
The format of the POST request should be http////{stagingrepo}
And it should have a parameter tag. So in entirety the request would be something like.
http;//localhost:8081/v1/service/staging/QA-REPO?tag='my_tag'

Do I need to pass authorization header as well in the request? Will the post request contain both authorization and content type header?

Please note that I have to pass the parameters in content type json as Nexus 3 accepts only Json format.

All examples show only POST request without any authorization. But I think I need an authorization header as well to first login to Nexus and then feed the parameters. Please help. Any working code will be really helpful.